# Integration runtime (self-hosted) node is not registered

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure data factory V2 and the problem I am facing is the Self-Hosted integration runtime is is getting Deregistered from the node automatically after running some time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i had this same error as per your screenshot.

1. Uninstall the integration runtime on your VM / Laptop
2. Go to ADF download the manual integration runtime (NOT THE EXPRESS; For some reason it didn't work for me)
3. Install the latest version of INtegration Runtime
   [image]
4. Restart your machine (recommended for registry purpose i guess!)
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you passing the valid "**Authentication Key**, while registering Integration Runtime".

There error message clearly says "Authentication Key is invalid".

[image]

For more details, refer "[Create and configure a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime)".

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.